# document.location - Not adding to history

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to use document.location(.href) on the onLoad event to redirect from one page (A) to another (B).

From my understanding, if I use document.location.href (as opposed to .replace), it should add  (A) to my history. However, this doesn't appear to be happening.

I've tried setting document.location, document.location.href, and using .assign, and none of these seem to add the first page to the history. Is there any JS technique that can be done via onLoad that will cause (A) to be in the history?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: FWIW, "document.location" was deprecated around 1996 when Netscape Navigator 3 came out - "window.location" (or synonyms such as "self.location", or just "location" on its own) is the preferred way to access the current location object. However browsers still support "d.l" so this is unlikely to be the cause of your problem. "location.href" should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify document.location.href, it will definitely add to the history.

[Try this demo page →](http://jsbin.com/ohusa)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready( 
function() 
{ 
   $('#hello').click( function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); document.location.href='http://www.google.com';}); 
} 
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello from JS Bin</p>
  <a id="hello" href="#">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you create a sample page where it shows that browser history is not changed?

Comment: ```<body><script>location.assign('http://www.google.com');</script></body>```

Answer (score 9):

'location.href', 'document.location' or any of these variations will only add an entry to the browser history if it came from a user initiated action. 
For example, if user clicks a button that fires a function that performs a 'location.href' it will be added to browser history, but if 'location.href' is called by an onload event - which is not  a user initiated action, it will not be added to the history.

Comment: Is there any reference?

Comment: Would be great with a reference on this behaviour and how to prevent it

Comment: For reference, here's the spec for the algorithm the location object runs when `href` is set: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#location-object-setter-navigate - note the conditions where the replacement flag is unset.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 location.replace('www.google.com');
```

This should put the page in your history.

Comment: That replaces the current item with the new page, removing the old one. That's more of a redirect.